# Visual C++ mdspan

Tags: c++, c++23

I have been waiting breathlessly for Microsoft to release their implementation of C++23 std::mdspan.  It came out today in V19 Preview 1.  I'm attempting to try it, but it doesn't seem to work.  Here's my code:

```
    std::vector<double> Bdat(dfcts.ndf * vbs.nvb);     // allocate the space
    using Dext = std::dextents<size_t, 2>;
    std::mdspan<double, Dext> B{ Bdat.data(), dfcts.ndf, vbs.nvb};    // create the mdspan
    B[0, 0] = 1.0;
```

The last line gives an error: "no operator "[]" matches these operands.  Please tell me I'm making an obvious syntatical error.  I really don't want to hear that I can create an mdspan but not use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MSVC does not currently support the multidimensional `operator[]` language feature, you may need to use another overload that accepts an `array` or `span` before this happens

```
B[std::array{0, 0}] = 1.0;
```

Comment: Thank you for the workaround!  I also note that the multidimensional [] operator is not expected in Preview 2 or 3.  It looks as if my code will be ugly for a while, but at least I can make it work.

Comment: Yikes!  I just checked out planned support for the multidimensional subscript operator (P2128R6) on cppreference.com and found that MSVC has no plans to support this.  Here's the link:  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/23 . Curiously, there are no published plans beyond the current preview (19.39 = 2022 release 17.9), which is a deviation from past practice.  I may have to switch to Clang.

Comment: @dr_eck That wiki page simply reflects the current state of implementation of features in the various compilers. It does not indicate whether features are planned to be implemented or not. In general, all major compilers strive for standards compliance so it is very unlikely that such a feature wouldn't get implemented eventually.

Comment: @Chrysler That wiki page stated that VS 2022 release 17.9 (i.e. 19.39) would support mdspan months before the first preview.  I was hoping that this trend would be continued, but I was clearly being too optimistic.

Comment: There is a Microsoft Issue for the multidimensional subscript operator here: [https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Missing-Multidimensional-Subscript-Opera/10525582](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Missing-Multidimensional-Subscript-Opera/10525582). As Microsoft claims to prioritize feature implementation based on community input, you may be interested to vote for it.